# InApp update functionality is not working am getting this error com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error: -3

Tags: android, in-app-update, app-update

I am trying to show the update via my App am getting following error

**com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error: -3**

this is the code for checking and updating App

```
public void checkAppUpdate(){
                    // Creates instance of the manager.

    // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
                    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

    // Checks whether the platform allows the specified type of update,
    // and checks the update priority.
                    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
                            Log.i("UpdateError123",appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()+"");

                            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
                                // Request an immediate update.

                                try {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                                appUpdateInfo,
                                // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                                AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                                // The current activity making the update request.
                                MainActivity.this,
                                // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                                1021);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                       Log.i("UpdateError",e.toString()+"");
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: I have successfully implemented In-App Update in my app and publish an article also. Just copy paste from there everything will work. Here is the link : https://medium.com/@sa159871/support-in-app-updates-in-android-a20ad11a4a80

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you didn't get the entire error description with `e.printStackTrace();` from your error handlers, or you are not using the android [DDMS tool](https://www.andreszsogon.com/debug-cordova-android-apps-with-ddms/) to debug errors:

```
com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error(-3): The API is not available on this device. (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallErrorCode#ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE)
```

This means that the **Play Store** and/or **Google Play Services** are not installed/enabled. On the emulator, make sure to use the "Google Play" ABI, which includes the store and required services.